# Retrieve map coordinates from firebase and plot on google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation

I have this project based on location tracking. This consists of two mobile applications where one application pushes GPS coordinates to firebase. And other application retrieve the coordinates. When I'm retrieving the coordinates and set them to the Latitude and Logitudes the application crashes without any Exceptions or errors. What have i done wrong here? Am i doing this the right way?

Following is my Code...

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    final Double[] latitu = {7.02343187};
    final Double[] longitu = {79.89658312};

    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("appontrain").child("location");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            latitu[0] = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue();
            longitu[0] = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("lon").getValue();

            Log.d("LatLon", latitu[0] + longitu[0] +"");
            Toast.makeText(LiveTrain.this, latitu[0].toString()+" - "+ longitu[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("Exception FB",databaseError.toException());
        }
    });

    LatLng trainLocation = new LatLng(latitu[0], longitu[0]);

    mop = new MarkerOptions();
    mop.position(trainLocation);
    mop.title("Train: Muthu Kumari");
    mop.icon(icon);
    mMap.addMarker(mop);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(trainLocation));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(trainLocation,13f));
}
```

When I hard-code the latitudes and longitudes to the `LatLng` object, the marker is showing on the app without any errors. When I set the values from the firebase it crashes. Please help me!

Following is the `logcat`

```
09-22 00:40:41.731 2711-2744/com.smartraveller.srt D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LiveTrain, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4621265793058976305, timestamp=1506021041714, fatal=1}]
09-22 00:40:41.831 5050-2755/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=crash,name=app_exception(_ae),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LiveTrain, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4621265793058976305, timestamp=1506021041714, fatal=1}]
09-22 00:40:41.841 5050-2755/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: app_exception(_ae), 86
09-22 00:40:41.841 5050-2755/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.smartraveller.srt', name='app_exception(_ae)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LiveTrain, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4621265793058976305, timestamp=1506021041714, fatal=1}]}
```

Following is the DB hierarchy.

[image: Firebase DB Hierarchy]

Comment: Share the picture of your database

Comment: @MalikAhsan i've edited the question with the picture of the database.

Comment: Hard to believe there is not a stack trace for the exception in the logcat.  If you're looking at the logcat in Android Studio, make sure you don't have a filter set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move all your firebase code inside the onMapready callback. Like this

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;
DatabaseReference myRef;

final Double[] latitu = {7.02343187};
final Double[] longitu = {79.89658312};

myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
.getReference().child("location");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot 
 dataSnapshot)
 {
        latitu[0] = (Double) 
dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue();
        longitu[0] = (Double) 
dataSnapshot.child("lon").getValue();

        Log.d("LatLon", latitu[0] + longitu[0] +"");
        Toast.
makeText(LiveTrain.this, latitu[0].toString()+" - "+ 
longitu[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
{
        Log.w("Exception FB",databaseError.toException());
    }
});

LatLng trainLocation = new LatLng(latitu[0], longitu[0]);

mop = new MarkerOptions();
mop.position(trainLocation);
mop.title("Train: Muthu Kumari");
mop.icon(icon);
mMap.addMarker(mop);
mMap
 .moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
.newLatLng(trainLocation));
 mMap
.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
.newLatLngZoom(trainLocation,13f));
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: the issue is still there!

Comment: Let me know if that helps

Comment: still no luck. I changed my code as you said. and i edited the question also. Now the map shows for like 2 seconds. and then the app crashes. 
I think the map is showing the hardcoded values. and when the firebase is plotting thr coordinates the app crashes.

Comment: The stack trace shows the same error? On which line it is crashing?

Comment: no stacktrace errors or any exceptions are shown in the log. I have added the logcat to the question. Seems like Firebase itself is crashing.

Comment: @MalikAhsan:  I suspect `appontrain` is the project name and is the root of the database tree.  It should not be included as a child on the database reference.

Comment: still no luck. same thing happens the activity crashes @MalikAhsan

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code. Thank you all

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    final Double[] latitu = {7.02343187};
    final Double[] longitu = {79.89658312};

    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("location");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            latitu[0] = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue();
            longitu[0] = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("lon").getValue();

            Log.d("LatLon", latitu[0] + longitu[0] +"");
            Toast.makeText(LiveTrain.this, latitu[0].toString()+" - "+ longitu[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("Exception FB",databaseError.toException());
        }
    });

    LatLng trainLocation = new LatLng(latitu[0], longitu[0]);

    mop = new MarkerOptions();
    mop.position(trainLocation);
    mop.title("Train: Muthu Kumari");
    mop.icon(icon);
    mMap.addMarker(mop);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(trainLocation));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(trainLocation,13f));
}
```